# Java MySQL BigDecimal Column cannot be null

Tags: java, mysql

I have a problem inserting `BigDecimal` into MySQL table. The MySQL column is type `decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00`.

The MYSQL Query

```
UPDATE `table` SET `Cost` = ? WHERE `Id` = 1
```

The JAVA code:

```
stmt.setBigDecimal(0, BigDecimal.valueOf("0.00"));
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

I get an error that says `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'Cost' cannot be null`

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Bound parameter indexes are 1-based, not 0-based in JDBC. 
In other words, the first bound parameter has the index "1", not "0".

Replacing "0" with "1" in the following line will fix your issue:

```
stmt.setBigDecimal(1, new BigDecimal("0.00"));
```

Comment: From `setBigDecimal`: Parameters:
`parameterIndex the first parameter is 1, the second is 2, ...`

Comment: @user2914191, yes exactly, but you've used `0` instead of `1`. You should use `1`.

Comment: yeah you are right, alas, in my actual code it's 1, and i thought i was just making some fundamental problem with BigDecimals but apparently the problem is elsewhere with the way my query is constructed. thanks anyway